# Is there one-to-one mapping of MachineFunction CFG and IR Function CFG in LLVM?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir, codegen, control-flow-graph

You can have CFGs at both the LLVM IR [`Function`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Function.html) level and CodeGen [`MachineFunction`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1MachineFunction.html) level. Is this a one-to-one mapping? I mean, are there same number of `(Machine)BasicBlock`s in those CFGs with similar control flows?I know the number of instructions could differ for obvious reason, but I am interested to know whether the structure remains same.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a one-to-one mapping? I mean, are there same number of
>   (Machine)BasicBlocks in those CFGs with similar control flows?

No there is no one-to-one mapping at the level of Basic blocks. One reason for this is that there is no exact replacement of "PHI" node possible. The generation of 'SELECT' and 'SELECT_CC' nodes restructures the Machine Basic Block representation.